# Define a legend for a MapBox Studio Project

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

Given that it is possible to request the [TileJSON](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-tilejson-metadata) for a MapBox project at `https://api.mapbox.com/v4/{mapId}.json?access_token={token}`, I was wondering if it was possible to define a legend for MapBox projects created using either **MapBox Studio** or **MapBox Studio Classic**.

Normally, I just define legends in the front-end of whichever site, but for this use case I was hoping to expose all tilesets through a public service accessed by any number of clients.

I know this was possible using TileMill.  Perhaps by editing, in the case of Studio Classic, the `project.yml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MapBox, defining legend HTML for projects built w/ Studio or Studio Classic is not possible.

I'll update this answer if that ever changes.